# Disable logging bad requests while unittest django app

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I have a tests in my Django app. They're working well, but i want to disable showing console logging like `.Bad Request: /api/v1/users/register/`

One of my tests code

```py
 def test_user_register_username_error(self):
        data = {
            'username': 'us',
            'email': 'mail@mail.mail',
            'password': 'pass123123',
            'password_again': 'pass123123'
        }

        url = self.register_url

        response = client.post(url, data=data)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 400)
        self.assertFalse(User.objects.filter(username='us').first())
```

Console output

```
Found 1 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.Bad Request: /api/v1/users/register/
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.414s

OK
```

Everything works nice, but i want to disable `Bad Request: /api/v1/users/register/` output to console. I double checked, there's no `print` or `logging` functions, that can possibly log this to console.

How can i disable messages like `Bad Request: /api/v1/users/register/` logging while tests

### **EDIT**

To make question more understandable here's current console output:

```
Found 22 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
...........Bad Request: /api/v1/users/register/
.Bad Request: /api/v1/users/register/
.Bad Request: /api/v1/users/register/
.Bad Request: /api/v1/users/register/
.Bad Request: /api/v1/users/register/
..Bad Request: /api/v1/users/register/
.Bad Request: /api/v1/users/activate/
.Bad Request: /api/v1/users/login/
.Bad Request: /api/v1/users/recovery/
Bad Request: /api/v1/users/recovery/
.Bad Request: /api/v1/users/register/
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 22 tests in 6.350s

OK
```

And what i expect:

```
Found 22 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
......................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 22 tests in 6.350s

OK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log only errors during the tests, and after they complete, return the normal logging level.

```
class SampleTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        """Reduce the log level to avoid messages like 'bad request'"""
        logger = logging.getLogger("django.request")
        self.previous_level = logger.getEffectiveLevel()
        logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        """Reset the log level back to normal"""
        logger = logging.getLogger("django.request")
        logger.setLevel(self.previous_level)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could do this in `setUpClass()` and `teardownClass()` to do it only once for the entire class.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using filters. In `settings.py` add:

```
import sys

class NotInTestingFilter(Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return (
            "pytest" in sys.modules
            or "django.test" in sys.modules
            or "django_webtest" in sys.modules
        )
```

and to the `LOGGING` variable (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/logging/) inside `settings.py` add:

```
   "filters": {
        "testing": {"()": NotInTestingFilter},
    },
     "loggers": {
        "django.request": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "ERROR",
            "filters": ["testing"],
            "propagate": False,
        },
    }
```